# returning object that caused error to a global errorhandler

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

i have written the following code which uses a global errorhandler that rectifies the error and resumes code again. right now i have labelled the lines and using 'Erl', i am checking which line caused the error and then accordingly finding the object and creating it.

What i want to do is to pass the object that caused the error to the errorhandler itself and then create that object and return control back to main procedure to resume from where it left off.

How to return the object that caused the error to an error handler? this way it would be more appropriate to handle some errors, instead of just returning an error message and error description.

as an example, i am letting the errorhandler handle creation of sheets if they are non-existent.

```
Option Explicit

'Worksheets: Public to VBproject as it may be used in almost every module.
Public WSCombined As Worksheet
Public WSResult As Worksheet

'Worksheet names: VBPublic to project as it may be used in almost every module.
Public Const Combined As String = "Combined data"
Public Const Result As String = "Result"

'Array: Public to VBproject as it may be used in almost every module.
Public Arr() As Variant

Sub Main()
On Error GoTo ERRHANDLER

Dim Rng As Range

With ThisWorkbook
'error labels for passing to Erl, so that corresponding sheet names can then be selected for sheet objects.
10001:    Set WSCombined = .Sheets(Combined)

10002:    Set WSResult = .Sheets(Result)

10003:    Set Rng = WSCombined.Rows(1).EntireRow

10004:    Arr = Rng

End With

EXITSUB:
' cleanup
Set WSCombined = Nothing
Set WSResult = Nothing
Exit Sub

ERRHANDLER:
If ErrorHandling(Err, ThisWorkbook, Erl) Then
    GoTo EXITSUB
Else
    Resume
End If

End Sub

Function ErrorHandling(objError As Object, Optional WB As Workbook, Optional ERlCode As Long) As Boolean

With objError
    Select Case .Number

    Case Is = 9                                 'subscript out of range
        Select Case ERlCode
        Case Is = 10001                         ' Worksheet: for Combined sheet
            Call SheetExists(WB, Combined)

        Case Is = 10002                         ' Worksheet: for Result sheet
            Call SheetExists(WB, Result)

        Case Is = 10003                         ' Array: Array not initialized
            Call IsArrayAllocated(Arr)

        Case Else

        End Select
        ErrorHandling = False                   ' resume again at same line, after sheet has been created.

    Case Is = 91                                ' Object variable or with variable not found
            Call IsArrayAllocated(Arr)

    Case Is = ""

    Case Else
        MsgBox objError.Number & " - " & objError.Description
        ErrorHandling = True
    End Select

End With

objError.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

End Function

Function SheetExists(WBook As Workbook, SHTName As String) As Worksheet

On Error GoTo ERRHANDLE
With WBook
    Set SheetExists = .Sheets(SHTName)
End With

EXITFUNC:
Exit Function

ERRHANDLE:
With WBook
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Set SheetExists = .Sheets.Add
    SheetExists.Name = SHTName
End With

Resume EXITFUNC

End Function

Function IsArrayAllocated(Arr As Variant) As Variant
'Courtesy: @Chip Pearson
' check if array is initialized, if not initialize it

On Error GoTo ERRHANDLE
IsArrayAllocated = (IsArray(Arr) And Not IsError(LBound(Arr, 1)) And LBound(Arr, 1) <= UBound(Arr, 1))

EXITFUNC:
Exit Function

ERRHANDLE:
ReDim Arr(0 To 0)
IsArrayAllocated = Arr
GoTo EXITFUNC

End Function
```

To tackle some errors, the other way i was thinking is to just have functions created which could have their own error handling code and rectify the error in place itself, instead of passing it to a global error handler of main proc.

e.g.

```
Sub Main()
On Error GoTo ERRHANDLER
Dim Rng As Range

With ThisWorkbook
set WSCombined = SheetExists(ThisWorkbook, Combined)
Set WSResult = SheetExists(ThisWorkbook, Result)
```

....
....

```
Function SheetExists(WBook As Workbook, SHTName As String) As Worksheet

On Error GoTo ERRHANDLE
With WBook
    Set SheetExists = .Sheets(SHTName)
End With

EXITFUNC:
Exit Function

ERRHANDLE:
With WBook
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Set SheetExists = .Sheets.Add
    SheetExists.Name = SHTName
End With
Resume EXITFUNC

End Function
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One answer to your specific ***question*** is to use another global object to store the object that threw the error in:

```
Public LastErrorObject As Object

Sub Main()    
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set LastErrorObject = ThisWorkbook
        Set WSCombined = .Sheets(Combined)
    End With
End Sub
```

However, this is incredibly cumbersome, because you need to keep track of it everywhere. Also, it still doesn't do much in the way of giving you the context for the error.

Your second idea is much better, and doesn't abuse the error handler as much because it both acknowleges that there may be an error ***and*** actively seeks to avoid errors instead of passively trying to deal with them.  For example, instead of indexing into `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets()` directly, you can do something like this to make sure you get a new sheet back:

```
Private Function GetOrCreateWorksheet(book As Workbook, name As String) As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo ForceNew

    Dim result As Worksheet
    Set result = book.Worksheets(name)

ForceNew:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        Set result = book.Worksheets.Add()
        result.name = name
    ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.source, Err.Description
    End If

    Set GetOrCreateWorksheet = result
End Function
```

Note that the error handling is only checking for the one specific error that you'll get if the sheet doesn't exit (Subscript out of range).

BTW and off topic, your Select Case syntax is overly convoluted - you only need to specify the case and can leave out the `Is =` syntax. It is also much easier to read with another level of indentation:

```
Select Case ERlCode
    Case 10001
        '...
    Case 10002
        '...
    Case Else
        '...
End Select
```